# How to force landscape mode when using mobile browser (Unity webgl)?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm working on a unity webgl project.
and i want to make it keep on landscape mode when it runs on a mobile environment.
i did try few codes but they were not working on both Android and IOS.
Is there anyone who can save me from this?

I did something like this.

```
<script>
    if(UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile == true){
        ScreenOrientation.lock('landscape');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: iOS Safari has no screen orientation API so it's impossible to lock the orientation on iOS at least as of iOS 13

Comment: @gman okay. i've just end up with the alert pop up to let the users set it manually.

Comment: There are other solutions. You can use CSS to rotate the content based on if the screen is landscape or portrait. You can also use CSS to show or hide the warning automatically. Unfornately many people have their phone locked in portrait mode and while a native app can force landscape a webpage can not, at least on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
lockAllowed = window.screen.lockOrientation(orientation);
```

You can find more information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation

on chrome something like this should work

```
var lockFunction =  window.screen.orientation.lock;
if (lockFunction.call(window.screen.orientation, 'landscape')) {
           console.log('Orientation locked')
} else {
            console.error('There was a problem in locking the orientation')
}
```

basically you only need to specify what orientation you need (landscape in your case).
This is a solution that I'm not sure will work on mobile.

So for mobile you can also try to create a manifest.json

```
<link rel="manifest" href="http://yoursite.com/manifest.json">

{
   "name":"A nice title for your web app",
   "display":"standalone",
   "orientation":"landscape"
}
```

A unity only solution can be to just rotate everything based on the x and y of the screen (by using canvas rect) so that you can rotate when x > y and rotate again when that change (the user should only see landscape this way).

Comment: iOS Safari has no screen orientation API

Comment: iOS Chrome is not working with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have a same question I'm adding my own answer.

For Android, yes you can lock it for a certain orientation.
For Ios, No simply you can not.

Aseets/plugins/webgl/MyPlugin.jslib

```
var MyPlugin = {
    IsMobile: function()
     {
         return UnityLoader.SystemInfo.mobile;
     },

    GoFullscreen: function()
    {

        var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById('#canvas');

        var orientation = (screen.orientation || {}).type || screen.mozOrientation || screen.msOrientation;

        var ActivateFullscreen = function()
        {
            if(orientation == "landscape-primary"){
                if (viewFullScreen.requestFullscreen) /* API spec */
                {  
                    viewFullScreen.requestFullscreen();
                    screen.orientation.lock("landscape-primary");
                }
                else if (viewFullScreen.mozRequestFullScreen) /* Firefox */
                {
                    viewFullScreen.mozRequestFullScreen();
                    screen.mozLockOrientation.lock("landscape-primary");
                }
                else if (viewFullScreen.webkitRequestFullscreen) /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
                {  
                    viewFullScreen.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                    screen.orientation.lock("landscape-primary");
                }
                else if (viewFullScreen.msRequestFullscreen) /* IE/Edge */
                {  
                    viewFullScreen.msRequestFullscreen();
                    screen.msLockOrientation.lock("landscape-primary");
                }
                viewFullScreen.removeEventListener('touchend', ActivateFullscreen);    
            }
        }
        viewFullScreen.addEventListener('touchend', ActivateFullscreen, false);
    },

    CheckOrientation: function(){
        var orientation = (screen.orientation || {}).type || screen.mozOrientation || screen.msOrientation;

        if(orientation == "landscape-primary")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    },
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MyPlugin);
```

Unity C#script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isLand;

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void GoFullscreen();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool IsMobile();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool CheckOrientation();


    //Whether your webgl is being playing on mobile devices or not.
    public bool isMobile()
    {
        #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
             return IsMobile();
        #endif
        return false;
    }

    //Activate Fullscreen.
    public static void ActivateFullscreen()
    {
        #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
            GoFullscreen();
        #endif
    }

    //Check current orientation.
    public bool isLandScape()
    {
        #if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
             return CheckOrientation();
        #endif
        return false;
    }

    //When your fullscreen button is clicked(touched).
    public void OnPointerClick()
    {
        //If you're using mobile devices.
        if (isMobile())
        {
            if (SystemInfo.operatingSystem.Contains("iOS"))
            {
                //Do Something.
            }
            else if (SystemInfo.operatingSystem.Contains("Android"))
            {
                if (isLand)
                {
                    //If Android and current Orientation is landscape-primary, Activate Fullscreen.
                    ActivateFullscreen();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Keep on checking the orientation.
        if (isMobile())
        {
            if (isLandScape())
            {
                isLand = true;
            }
            else if (!isLandScape())
            {
                isLand = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, I think you will get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the only long-term viable and universal option you'll have is to manage the screen orientation yourself within your game. Any other option can and will most likely change over time and/or might not work within specific versions of certain browser due to said browser's limitation when it comes to mobile-related features.

Also, if you lock out a certain orientation of your mobile (like the portrait orientation), you cut yourself off from the majority of mobile users due to the nature of the 1-hand-yield mobile device method which is far easier on portrait than landscape. Remember that over 90% of the users prefer, when given the option, to view a webpage in portrait. In 2019, data of over 3 millions users displayed that that over 80% prefers to watch video in portrait mode even if it means the video is scaled down to the portrait's width. This is due to the 1-hand-yield mobile device method I previously explained: In General, people who watch their phone while having 1 hand tied to a task such as holding a bar in a bus or subway or while holding a book at school or while taking a smoke break or even just while socializing (speaking with others while holding and taking a look at social media, a trend far too common for the common sens), people ends up being adapted to the negative sides of portrait oriented mobile uses and those people might even develops some hates to the act of being forced to hold their phone in both hands.

Except for gaming, more than 3/4 of the reasons why you have to hold your phone in both hand when you're used to use it in 1 hand is to take control of some issues as fast as possible. It's not for nothing that, in general, adaptative web design is promoting portrait over landscape view when displaying their layout to the mobile users.

Still, if you still want to have some sort of locking mechanism for the orientation of your mobile game in unity, then you got a few possible options, but they ultimately all roam around the idea that you got to turn your in-game screen around when the width become smaller or equal to the height of the screen. Lots of people will recommend doing the "look up" call in the Update function or LateUpdate function, but that's just an huge waste task memory. You can easily do it through a coroutine loop every 5 secs which, when it comes to Unity, coroutines are independent from the update call and it allows you to set a fixed amount of secs between each rotation analyse test.

Remember that most of the functions that returns floats or integers from an API, like the integer number of screen.width and screen.height that represent the pixels counts, in Unity, will generate those floats and integers as new memory data blocks that has to be digested by the Garbage Collector. If you do it every frame, that's 60+ integers generated per secs and if you consider that WebGL on mobile is tied tightly the mobile browsers' memory allocation and that memory is limited by the mobile OS and can have some additional memory complication done by users' (like lots of active tabs), you know you want to make sure the WebGL build's garbage collector has as little to do each frame as possible. (Which is actually the user's browser cache cleaner, hence not the mobile device's own dedicated memory cleaner. It's FAR more slower.)

The only issue that come from having Unity WebGL to rotate the content is that you got to apply it differently on both the UI and in-game cameras, if the UI is not 3D world-related. At least, the camera in Unity are rendered-pixel related so you don't have much more to do than rotate the camera by 90 or -90 degrees on local. (The difference between using 90 or -90 is important as it determines where the users' face directed camera will be located: left or right. Remember that not many people hold their phone in reverse portrait, so you can assume a majority will hold it in regular portrait)

For the UI, that's where the catch is kinda bigger. If you uses any form of auto-sizing in your UI, you want the keep the UI within a parent which you can rotate and change its rect sizes based on the initially collected screen's width and height. (When you collect and set the screen width and height as the game launches, you just have to make sure the width is the biggest and the height is the smallest of the 2 size number as you don't know how the user will be holding his/her device at that moment.)

Currently, there's only one rare, yet still big problem that will come your way: Multi-tasking screens. For the last 3-4 years, mobiles devices have becomes strong enough to be multi-tasking if it's not the device's manufacturer, it's the browser that will allow users to have 2 pages in view at once (cutting the screen in half). At this moment, it's not yet really possible to know if an user does such thing so you can't do much about it, but it should remain in the corner of your mind in case some of your users complains that your game doesn't work well when they multi-task such as having the game in 1 half of their screen and whatever homework they're working on on the 2nd half of it. ;)